# Excel's BINOMDIST cumulative probability =1?

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I would like to calculate the following: the probability of 145 or more successes out of 180 trials in a 2-way choice task. Each trial has an 0.5 probability of success.

I tried to use Excel's BINOMDIST function, calculating this probability as:
1-P(<=144). However, the cumulative probability for this: BINOMDIST(144,180,0.5,TRUE) resulted in 1.

How should I interpret this? What did I do wrong?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: $$P(X\le 144)\approx 1-2\cdot 10^{-17}$$, so $$P(X>144)\approx 2\cdot 10^{-17}$$

Comment: More precisely, $$\frac{31667651931023347066212723008766369541}{
1532495540865888858358347027150309183618739122183602176}
$$

Comment: You calculated the above value and the result is the below value. Within Excel's accuracy , you get $1$

Comment: @Peter You left out the $-$ in the exponent

Comment: Oops, you are right.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Yes, I thought that it's because it's so close to 1 that excel it rounds it up to 1, but I'm wondering how I should put this probability value in a paper. just simply refer to it as p<0.0001? Or what would be the proper way?

Comment: By the way, didn't you mean that P(X≤144)≈2⋅10−17, instead of P(X≤144)≈1−2⋅10−17? Or am I confused?
 
And than what follows is P(X>=145)≈1-2⋅10−17 ?

Comment: No, it is almost sure that we have not more than $144$ hits, so the probability for not more than $144$ hits must be close to $1$. This means that is almost impossible to have more than $144$ hits. $P(X\le 144)$ is the cumulated probability, which you calculated. $1$ minus this is the probability of the complementary event, which you finally want to know.

Comment: Oh, yeah yeah, of course, thank you!

Comment: $p<0.0001$ is a proper way because $0.0001$ is already a small probability and you mention that the given probability is even smaller. It is a matter of taste if we write, for example, $p<10^{-6}$ instead.

Comment: @anna Welcome to math stack exchange! Hope you enjoy this site!

Comment: Yes, absolutely! great answers, super fast!

Answer (score 0):

The normal approximation says you should expect $90$ successes with a standard deviation of $\sqrt {45}\approx 7$ so you are $8$ standard deviations out. The probability of $145$ or more is very small, so when it is subtracted from $1$ you can't see it